# Dynamics Circular Motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, everyday-life, free-body-diagram, centripetal-force

For circular motion to occur a centripetal force is required. In the case of a turning bicycle, where does the centripetal force come from, since the force of friction is not great enough and the normal force acts perpendicular to the ground?

Comment: Force of friction is strong enough in most cases. For very high  speeds, the roads are banked (the road is built obliquely so that a component of the normal reaction acts as the centripetal force).

Answer (score 0):

The frictional force is quite sufficient for providing the centripetal force to turn. It is only at high speeds that friction may not be enough and you may skid.